# Child windows shown on separate window ( wpf application)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-interface, mvvm

I'm trying to get a grasp on WPF and MVVM and have been making good progress .I was designed my applications User Interface Parent as a Window object from which I created a menu on the menu when user select menu item another window object is shown and so on . I read there is no MDI in WPF . But my problem is each window object is shown asa sepearate window.I want to dock the child windows on the parent window.(child parent relationship)
Is there any good Application UI for my application .(I need an alternative concept for MDI in wpf)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using tabs control in wpf. This is usually used instead of MDI in wpf and is also recommended by microsoft. Check out the link [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32362/Tabbed-MDI-in-WPF) for an example of implementing MDI like functionality using tab.

For more details about tab control you can check out the following

http://codingtales.blogspot.co.uk/2010/02/creating-complete-tabbed-interface-in.html
http://tech.pro/tutorial/730/the-wpf-tab-control-inside-and-out

You can also check out [Avalondock](http://avalondock.codeplex.com/) but I have never tried it out

The link [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Multiple-Document-059b96a8) might also help

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is there any sample UI you have ,this will be great help for me

Comment: I like the AvalonDock that nice looking let me try this thanks

Comment: Sure. If the answer was useful then please upvote and/or tick mark it. :)

Comment: If you are talking about MDI then Tab control is what I used because I found it the easiest to implement and there is a lot of support on the net just in case you came across an issue. It also supports MVVM pattern among other things.

Comment: @ChrisF, please see my question I edited